# using cuda device kernel from Java?

Tags: java, jcuda

I am using Java with Jcuda library to access CUDA.. I was able to run a simple application ( like vectorAdd).. However, the code of my Kernel stated getting very large.. is there a way to use **device** function in the kerenel.cu file? I knew that it is possible if I use CUDA C , but with Java I got an error? can any one help

thanks in advance

Comment: I wonder how one can write a question here, and say that he "got an error", and seemingly not even *consider* to mention **what** error this was...

Answer (score 0):

I think the error you get is most likely CUDA_ERROR_NOT_FOUND. Please check if you put "extern C" before your `__device__` function. Otherwise, it won't be found in the symbol table.